# Application dash as default

Tags: unity-dash, default, lenses

When pressing the super button the dash opens. It will always open in the home format. On the bottom you can choose between different lenses, the second one being the application lens with filter functionality. Is there a possibility to set the application lens as the default when opening the dash?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately this feature has not yet been added to Unity, but it should be there in 12.04.

You can track this bug as mentioned by doug in the comments:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/885738

Comment: There are some proposed changes to the Dash for 12.04, tracking bug - https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/885738

Answer (score 1):

You can also use shortcuts:

- <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> = File lens
- <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> = Application lens
- <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd> = Music lens

Comment: Hm.. I can't get this to work