# How to customise Ubuntu to have the following features?

Tags: customization

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Application dash as default](https://askubuntu.com/questions/79961/application-dash-as-default)

Everyone keeps telling me that Linux/Ubuntu is much more customizable than Windows but I seem to be having a problem trying to do the following changes:

- When pressing Home Dash button on the left I want Ubuntu to go straight to the applications tab.
- From here I do not want it showing me recently used apps or apps available for download. How do I disable these?
- How do I move the minimize, exit and maximize buttons to the right side of the window instead the left side of the window?
- Also how can I change the orange exit buttons to the colour blue?
- When clicking and dragging the mouse, an orange box appears, how can I change it to blue to match my theme?

Me a Windows fan is really digging Ubuntu's new interface compared to my Windows 8 release preview which is a living nightmare.

Comment: It is preferred if you can post separate questions instead of combining your questions into one. That way, it helps the people answering your question and also others hunting for at least one of your questions. Thanks!

Comment: exact duplicate of the following: 1. http://askubuntu.com/q/79961/25798
2. http://askubuntu.com/questions/28977/how-to-hide-recent-files-and-most-used-apps and http://askubuntu.com/questions/37747/how-to-remove-apps-available-for-download-from-the-applications-lens
3. http://askubuntu.com/q/44187/25798 
4. http://askubuntu.com/questions/85786/how-do-i-change-the-colors-of-the-ambiance-radiance-themes
5. http://askubuntu.com/questions/85786/how-do-i-change-the-colors-of-the-ambiance-radiance-themes

Comment: Hi and welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Please don't post multiple questions in a single post. And, all of your questions have already been answered in other questions in the site. Take a look at the above question link that I have posted and go through them one by one closely. If you have any issues with any of them, you may then proceed to ask a new question with just that one issue at a time. That way, our site will work best. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

The **First** Customization is already available as `Super+A` . And currently by pressing Single button `Super` or `Dash` for directly accessing Applications menu is not available, would be illogical too *( i suppose)* .

---

For your **Second** Optimization go to **system Settings  >> Privacy >> >> Applications**  select the **+** to add the applications you don't want to see in the recently Used as here

[image]

[image]

[image]

---

For **Third** Customization Use [Ubuntu Tweak](https://askubuntu.com/a/75459/63025) , then under

> **TWEAK >> Desktop >> window >> windows control button positions>> select Right**

---

For your **Fourth** Customization refer the [Answers here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/107013/how-to-change-color-of-unity-workspace-border-and-window-resize)

Hope this Helps.